# Comparar los campos de una misma columna

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
create table cumpleanios(
   Id_cumpleanios pk ai,
   Id_user mediumint, 
   cumpleanios varchar(12)
);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es comparar el campo `cumpleanios` para saber si a un usuario ya se le insertó el cumpleaños para el siguiente año, y de no ser así, insertarlo.

```
Id_cumpleanios Id_user Cumpleanios
        1         5     14/09/2017
        2         7     28/03/2017
        3         8     08/10/2017
        4         9     03/07/2017
        5         7     28/03/2018
```

Comencé un procedimiento almacenado y mi idea es mandarlo llamar desde un evento que se ejecute cada año (haré esto también para otras tablas).

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertCumpleanios;
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCumpleanios(IN anioLast varchar(15))
    BEGIN 
    -- Variables donde almacenar lo que nos traemos desde el SELECT             
        DECLARE p_iduser TINYINT;
        DECLARE p_anio varchar(5);
        DECLARE p_mes varchar(3);
        DECLARE p_dia varchar(3);
        DECLARE anioAct varchar(5); 
        DECLARE p_total TINYINT;      
    -- Variable para controlar el fin del bucle
        DECLARE fin TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    -- El SELECT que vamos a ejecutar
        DECLARE cumple_cursor CURSOR FOR

            SELECT u.Id_user, DAY(c.cumpleanios), MONTH(c.cumpleanios), YEAR(c.cumpleanios)
            FROM cumpleanios c INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.Id_user = c.Id_user WHERE u.Estado = 'Disponible' ORDER BY YEAR(c.cumpleanios) ASC;

    -- Condición de salida
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=1;       

        OPEN cumple_cursor;
            get_cumple: loop
                FETCH cumple_cursor INTO p_iduser, p_dia, p_mes, p_anio;
                IF fin=1 then
                    LEAVE get_orden;
                END IF;

                SELECT p_iduser, p_dia, p_mes, p_anio;  -- almacena fila de datos actual
                -- SELECT count(DISTINCT campo) FROM tabla
                SET p_total = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p_iduser));

                SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) as anioActual;   -- Obtiene el año actual

                SELECT u.Id_user, DAY(c.cumpleanios), MONTH(c.cumpleanios), YEAR(c.cumpleanios)
                FROM cumpleanios c INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.Id_user = c.Id_user 
                WHERE u.Estado = 'Disponible' ORDER BY YEAR(c.cumpleanios) ASC LIMIT p_total;

                IF p_anio < anioActual
                INSERT INTO cumpleanios(Id_user, cumpleanios) VALUES(p_iduser, CONCAT(p_anio, '-', p_mes, '-', p_dia));

           END LOOP get_cumple;
       CLOSE cumple_cursor;

    END $$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hola Spoke. Como nota, no uses `<code>` para bloques de codigo. Usa el boton  `{}` que le da una indentacion para que el codigo se vea con resaltado. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo muy bien la causa por la cual necesita almacenar la fecha de cumpleaños, por año, de cada usuario, almacenando el día y mes por usuario ya tendría la fecha de cumpleaños (no importando el año), sin embargo, como no tengo todo el contexto de su necesidad, cualquier comentario sería especulativo.

Algunos consejos:

- Almacenar fechas como tipo de dato texto (VARCHAR), no es una práctica recomendada en la gran mayoría de casos.
- Los cursores son útiles, pero siempre que se puedan evitar, es recomendable hacerlo.

Le propongo una opción alternativa (sin cursor), puede ajustarla según necesite (evalúe posibles problemas de performace):

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertCumpleanios`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cumpleanios`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cumpleanios` (
    ->   `Id_cumpleanios` SERIAL,
    ->   `Id_user` MEDIUMINT, 
    ->   `cumpleanios` VARCHAR(12)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `cumpleanios`
    ->   (`Id_user`, `cumpleanios`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (5, '14/09/2017'),
    ->   (7, '28/03/2017'),
    ->   (8, '08/10/2017'),
    ->   (9, '03/07/2017'),
    ->   (7, '28/03/2018');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `Id_cumpleanios`,
    ->   `Id_user`,
    ->   `cumpleanios`
    -> FROM
    ->   `cumpleanios`;
+----------------+---------+-------------+
| Id_cumpleanios | Id_user | cumpleanios |
+----------------+---------+-------------+
|              1 |       5 | 14/09/2017  |
|              2 |       7 | 28/03/2017  |
|              3 |       8 | 08/10/2017  |
|              4 |       9 | 03/07/2017  |
|              5 |       7 | 28/03/2018  |
+----------------+---------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertCumpleanios`(
    ->   IN `anioLast` VARCHAR(15)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   INSERT INTO `cumpleanios` (`Id_user`, `cumpleanios`)
    ->   SELECT
    ->     `c`.`Id_user`,
    ->     DATE_FORMAT(
    ->       DATE_ADD(
    ->         STR_TO_DATE(`c`.`cumpleanios`, '%d/%m/%Y'),
    ->       INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
    ->     '%d/%m/%Y')
    ->   FROM (
    ->     SELECT `Id_user`, COUNT(`cumpleanios`) `count`
    ->     FROM `cumpleanios`
    ->     WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`cumpleanios`, '%d/%m/%Y'))
    ->           IN (`anioLast`, `anioLast` + 1)
    ->     GROUP BY `Id_user`
    ->     HAVING `count` = 1
    ->   ) `der`
    ->     INNER JOIN `cumpleanios` `c` ON
    ->                `der`.`Id_user` = `c`.`Id_user`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `InsertCumpleanios`(YEAR(NOW()));
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `Id_cumpleanios`,
    ->   `Id_user`,
    ->   `cumpleanios`
    -> FROM
    ->   `cumpleanios`;
+----------------+---------+-------------+
| Id_cumpleanios | Id_user | cumpleanios |
+----------------+---------+-------------+
|              1 |       5 | 14/09/2017  |
|              2 |       7 | 28/03/2017  |
|              3 |       8 | 08/10/2017  |
|              4 |       9 | 03/07/2017  |
|              5 |       7 | 28/03/2018  |
|              6 |       5 | 14/09/2018  |
|              7 |       8 | 08/10/2018  |
|              8 |       9 | 03/07/2018  |
+----------------+---------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ver [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qdoLUhWzbW9KTQVgUu8buT/0).

Comment: Hola muchas gracias, no lo había pensado de esa forma, no necesito el año. con eso me hiciste entender más cosas, y el procedimiento me será muy útil para otros casos en los que si necesito tener registros de un mismo usuario por año. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de @wchiquito es la adecuada a tu pregunta, pensaba proponer algo muy similar, pero me voy a limitar a la parte de la consulta para la obtención de las fechas nuevas a insertar que si es distinta a dicha respuesta:

```
SET @anionuevo = 2018;

INSERT INTO cumpleanios (Id_user, cumpleanios)
select c.id_user,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@anionuevo,'-',month(m.cumpleanios),'-',day(m.cumpleanios)), '%Y-%m-%d')
       FROM cumpleanios c
       INNER JOIN (select  Id_user, 
                            MAX(cumpleanios) as cumpleanios
                            from cumpleanios
                            group by Id_user
                   ) m
                   ON m.id_user = c.id_user
                   AND m.cumpleanios = c.cumpleanios
       WHERE YEAR(m.cumpleanios) < @anionuevo;
```

#### ¿Que hace?

- Obtenemos la fecha de cumpleaños máxima para cada usuario
- Únicamente en los usuarios que no tiene cargada la fecha para `@anionuevo`, es decir `WHERE YEAR(m.cumpleanios) < @anionuevo`, calculamos la nueva fecha componiéndola de el día/mes y de `@anionuevo`

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu procedimiento me acaba de dar una idea para otras inserciones que me hacen falta, ya había considerado seleccionar la fecha mas reciente (usando MAX) pero al final no supe como aplicarla